# Restriction of a diffeomophism is still a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I have an open box $U = I_1 \times ... \times I_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (so each $I_j$ is a non-empty open interval) and $F$ defines a diffeomorphims on $U$. What I was wondering was, if take $x_1 \in I_1$, is $F(x_1, \cdot)$ still a diffeomorphim on $I_2 \times...I_n$? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is a diffeomorphism from $I_1\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n$ onto some subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^n$, then your map is a diffeomorphism from $I_2\times\cdots\times I_n$ onto $F\bigl(\{x_1\}\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n\bigr)$, since, if $G=F^{-1}$, both $F|_{\{x_1\}\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n}$ and $G|_{F(\{x_1\}\times I_2\times\cdots\times I_n)}$ re differentiable and each one is the inverse of the other one.

Comment: Would it be the same if I wanted $C^r$-diffeomorphism as well?

Comment: Yes, it would. ${}$